# Swift 2.1- tabBarController!.selectedIndex return massive integer

Tags: swift, integer, uitabbarcontroller, selectedindex

I am needing to put the `tabBarController!.selectedIndex` number inside a constant.

I am expecting a number between 0 and 3 depending on what tab I choose, but instead I get numbers like `2147483647`

Any ideas why this is?

The code is:

```
let selectedTab = tabBarController!.selectedIndex
print(selectedTab)
```

Comment: Any chance this applies: "However, if the selected view controller is currently the More navigation controller, this property contains the value NSNotFound."

Comment: Not the more tab, but the tab that the first tab that is used at launch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That value is NSNotFound. In this case it seems to represent "no selection".

Comment: Sorry I didn't clarify, this applies to the tab that is shown on launch - so no switching takes place. So the tab that is used at launch does not return a number?

Comment: As you mentioned in your answer, whether you were asking at the right time was exactly the question. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to *Joshua's* answer and *Philip's* comment for getting me on the right track.

The problem was that I had put the constant in my `viewWillAppear` method which meant it was not reading the VC that I was selecting, because it hadn't appeared yet.

The `NSNotFound` was therefore triggered, because the view had not loaded yet.

Comment: if the selected view controller is currently the More navigation controller, selectedIndex contains the value NSNotFound. moreNavigationController property always contains a valid More navigation controller, even if a More button is not displayed on the screen.

Comment: That makes sense, but I never said I was targeting the more navigation controller or that it was selected.